# Is constancy of fiber degree analytic-local on the source in a finite flat family?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, flatness

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ be a closed subscheme, and let $\pi \colon X \to \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ be a finite flat map. For a point $p \in X(\mathbb{C})$, is it true that we can find an arbitrarily small open neighborhood $U \ni p$ (in the analytic topology) such that for some analytic-open neighborhood $V \ni \pi(p)$, the degree of the fiber $\pi^{-1}(q) \cap U$ is constant over $q \in V$?

What I know so far: I know that fiber degree is constant in finite flat families, but I'm interested in whether this property is analytic-local on the source in the above sense.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question correctly, but if something is constant, then it is certainly also locally constant in whatever topology you want to consider.

Comment: @MarcPaul No, it is well-known that the degree of $\pi^{-1}(q)$ is constant over $q \in \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$. However, I have no idea whether the degree of $\pi^{-1}(q) \cap U$ is constant on some neighborhood of $\pi(q)$, although I suspect the answer is yes.

Comment: I see, thank you. Would the following be a counter-example? Take $X = \mathbb A^1 \sqcup \mathbb A^1$ the disjoint union of two lines, with natural projection $\pi$, let $p \in X(\mathbb C)$ be the origin of one of the lines, and let $U$ be the complement in $X$ of the origin of the other line. Then for $q = \pi(p)$ we have $\#(\pi^{-1}(q) \cap U) = 1$ while for all other $q$ this degree is two, so you cannot find a neighborhood $V$ around $\pi(p)$ on which this degree is constant.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out this counterexample. I have now edited the question to correct for this problem.

Comment: But in the new version, I think we can just take $U = X(\mathbb C)$ and $V = \mathbb A^1(\mathbb C)$, right?

Comment: You're right, I'm having a hard time posing this question correctly. I have now edited it once more!